# Alternative of ExpressionEvaluationUtils in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

We were using `ExpressionEvaluationUtils`(Deprecated) class to evaluate expression when using Spring 3.2.8. Now we have migrated our product from Spring 3 to Spring 4.

```
final Object argument = ExpressionEvaluationUtils.evaluate("argument", stringArray[0], this.pageContext);
```

In Spring 4, they have removed this util file. I have search some alternative util/service but didn't get any result.

Can somebody tell me what is the alternative of ExpressionEvaluationUtils class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- [Spring Expression Language (EL)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions)
- Spring `ExpressionFactory`:

  ```
  ELContext elContext =  pageContext.getELContext();
  JspFactory jf = JspFactory.getDefaultFactory();
  JspApplicationContext jac = jf
                   .getJspApplicationContext(pageContext.getServletContext());
  ExpressionFactory ef = jac.getExpressionFactory();
  ValueExpression val = ef.createValueExpression(elContext, "your expression", resultClass);
  ```

Comment: How does "argument", stringArray[0] translate into "your expression" ?

Answer (score 1):

it is mentioned in [JavaDoc for that class](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ExpressionEvaluationUtils.html):

> Deprecated as of Spring 3.2, in favor of the JSP 2.0+ native support
>   for embedded expressions in JSP pages (also applying to tag
>   attributes)

So use JSP 2.0+ native expressions instead.